# Запуск dind в gitlab

Tags: docker, gitlab

Столкнулся с проблемой запуска dind в gitlab ci.
.gitlab-ci.yml :

```
image: docker:latest

variables:
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay

services:
- docker:dind
before_script:
- docker version
- docker info

build1:
  script:
  - docker login docker.xxx.ru:1234
```

Ответы:

```
$  docker:dind
Waiting for services to be up and running...

*** WARNING: Service runner-7dd9e4f9-project-183-concurrent-0-docker probably didn't start properly.

service runner-7dd9e4f9-project-183-concurrent-0-docker-wait-for-service did timeout

 mount: permission denied (are you root?)
 Could not mount /sys/kernel/security.
 AppArmor detection and --privileged mode might break.
 mount: permission denied (are you root?)

$ docker info
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?

$  docker version
Client:
 Version:  1.12.6
 API version:  1.24
 Go version:  go1.6.4
 Git commit:  78d1802
 Built:  Tue Jan 10 20:38:45 2017
 OS/Arch:  linux/amd64
```

!!! server нет

кто-нибудь сталкивался с таким?

Comment: если запускать на [http://gitlab.com/](http://gitlab.com/) то все работает

Comment: У меня было такое, что `docker version` выдавал только секцию **Client**. У вас либо runner не было запущен с параметром `--docker-privileged`, либо модуль `overlay` не был [установлен правильно](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/ci/docker/using_docker_build.md#using-the-overlayfs-driver)